# How to pass dynamic (user info) parameters as variable to azure pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

i have CI/CD environment in azure devops.i specially want to get the user name who pushed his code to trigger pipeline.i want to use this info as a variable inside the pipeline.do you guys know how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we do have a predefined [Build variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) .

We can directly use `$(Build.RequestedFor)` to get the the original user who kick off pipeline

If you want to pass this variable to any other customized variable/parametes.

You could **use Logging Commands** to set value during your build pipeline. `##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar` The first task can set a variable, and following tasks in the same phase are able to use the variable. The variable is exposed to the following tasks as an environment variable.

> **Define and modify your variables in a script**
>
> To define or modify a variable from a script, use the task.setvariable
> logging command. Note that the updated variable value is scoped to the
> job being executed, and does not flow across jobs or stages. Variable
> names are transformed to uppercase, and the characters "." and " " are
> replaced by "_".
>
> For example, Agent.WorkFolder becomes AGENT_WORKFOLDER. On Windows,
> you access this as %AGENT_WORKFOLDER% or $env:AGENT_WORKFOLDER. On
> Linux and macOS, you use $AGENT_WORKFOLDER.

More details please take a look at this tutorial [Define and modify your variables in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?tabs=powershell&view=azure-devops#set-in-script) You could also look at this blog: [Use Azure DevOps Variables Inline powershell in build and release pipelines](https://thinkrethink.net/2017/12/07/use-vsts-variables-inline-powershell/)

Comment: You do not need use `##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar` to pass user name because  `$(Build.RequestedFor)` available in all pipeline tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Devops passes that information to pipelines. Check `Build.RequestedFor` variable: [Build variables (DevOps Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services), [How are the identity variables set?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#identity_values)

> In Git or TFVC by the Continuous integration (CI) triggers, the
> Build.RequestedFor and Build.RequestedForId values are based on the
> person who pushed or checked in the changes.

How to use variables you can find here: [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)